# calculate the average in sql and update it using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to calculate the average in sql.There are multiple entries with the same atr_name but with different scores. Need to calculate the average of every individual atr_name score and update it in the database table. 
I am trying to fetch the data into an arraylist. But I am not getting the correct results. It is just giving me one name with wrong average.

```
 ArrayList<String> sc = new ArrayList<String>();

resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select atr_name, avg(newScore) from scores");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    sc.add(resultSet.getString("atr_name"));
    sc.add(resultSet.getString("avg(newScore)"));
}

for (String a : sc) {
    System.out.println(" " + a);
}
```

Comment: You need to add GROUP BY atr_name in your query after FROM scores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause.  In most databases, it would not even run, but MySQL permits in (in certain modes), and as a result you are getting a single record, with a table level average, and some `atr_name` value from a certain record.

But, you might also want to use a map to store the `atr_name` keys and their average scores.

```
Map<String, Double> sc = new HashMap<>();
String sql = "SELECT atr_name, AVG(newScore) AS avgScore FROM scores GROUP BY atr_name";
rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next()) {
    sc.put(rs.getString("atr_name"), rs.getDouble("avgScore"));
}

sc.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("atr_name: " + k + ", average score: " + v));
```

Note that I am calling `ResultSet#getDouble` to obtain the average of the `newScore` column.  Even if the `newScore` column is integer, taking the average should return a floating point (I think).

Comment: It solved the problem, getting the desired output. But I also want to update this average in a different table when I have the atr_name. I actually made "scores" table to enter the new scores and just to calculate the average but the end result will be continuously updating the average in the other table. Whenever a user enters a new score, the average should be updated. A logical help behind that will be helpful.

Comment: You should look into using a trigger, if you really want to do that.  But, I don't recommend it.  The average is derived from the data in your table; it is not original data, so I vote for _not_ storing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should looks like this:

```
ArrayList<String> sc = new ArrayList<String>();

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select atr_name, avg(newScore) AS avgScore from scores GROUP BY atr_name;");
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
           sc.add(resultSet.getString("atr_name"));
           sc.add(resultSet.getString("avgScore"));
        }


        for(String a:sc)
        {
            System.out.println(" " + a);
        }
```

Comment: It solved the problem, getting the desired output. But I also want to update this average in a different table when I have the atr_name. I actually made "scores" table to enter the new scores and just to calculate the average but the end result will be continuously updating the average in the other table. Whenever a user enters a new score, the average should be updated. A logical help behind that will be helpful. I am using mysql with jdbc

Comment: From my perspective of view, I wouldn't do that. You have scores, you just need to create query which will always calculate fresh average value instead of updating that value in another table. But if you want you can create new issue and someone will help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Next time if you ask a database question that please add the name of the database and preferable the version from the database. SQL is different on different databases.

In your statement you are missing a group by clause.

try select atr_name, avg(newScore) from scores group by atr_name